# View Source in Chrome Font Missing

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion, fonts

I've just installed a font management software on OS X called FontExplorer X Pro and have installed a few new fonts. Unwittingly it seems I may have accidentally messed around with some of the system defaults, possibly causing the removal of whatever font it is that Chrome uses in it's View Source menu (like so:)

[image: font missing presumably]

So two solutions in my mind are to either:

1. Edit the Chrome config file to specify a new font for source display
2. Reinstall the default font (whatever that may be)

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing fontd databases and cache files:

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove; atsutil server -shutdown
```

Source windows seem to use the fixed width font selected in Settings > Show advanced settings > Customize fonts.